# What's the Internal language of a groupoid?

Tags: type-theory, groupoids

Is there any existing literature on what the internal language of a groupoid might look like?

Please excuse the syntax bashing of this amateur, but i came up with:

symmetry (structural rule):
$$
\frac{
  \Gamma  \vdash Y : e : X \dashv \Delta
}{
  \Delta  \vdash X : e : Y \dashv \Gamma
}
$$

abstraction introduction:
$$
\frac{
  \Gamma, x : A  \vdash D : e : B \dashv C : x, \Delta
}{
  \Gamma  \vdash A \leftrightarrow B : \lambda x. e : D \leftrightarrow C \dashv \Delta
}
$$

(I'm not sure whether perhaps I should just have $A$ and $B$ with $C := A$ and $ D := B$, or should I go in the other direction and use $ A \rightarrow B : \lambda x.e : C \rightarrow D$. Similarly, I'm unsure whether I want one $x$ used twice, or an $x$ and a $y$.)

abstraction elimination:
$$
\frac{
  \Gamma  \vdash A \leftrightarrow B : f : D \leftrightarrow C \dashv \Delta
 \qquad
 \Gamma \vdash C : e : A \dashv \Delta
}{
  \Gamma  \vdash D : f e : B \dashv \Delta
}
$$

for a closed grouoid, which "seems truthy" to me.

The idea of sharing the terms between paired typing judgements is downright loony, I'll freely admit, but corresponds to the "symmetry by construction" of an arbitrary groupoid.

If this does turn out to be...not wrong, is it useful? I don't much intuition for what one can do with the "pointful" lambda parameters that is easier to do than with the "point free" external language.

If it helps, I would like to use this stuff to construct a isomorphism between dependent sums [not generalize to "dependent isomorphisms", which seem absurd to me at this stage] in a suitable groupoid. Even more concretely, imagine coercing GADTs in System $F_C$, and using the coercions of the variant to coerce other fields which otherwise couldn't be coerced.

Comment: _A_ groupoid does not have enough structure to support an interesting internal language. The 2-category of groupoids has enough structure to interpret Martin-Löf type theory, albeit without univalence.

Comment: @ZhenLin With univalence for propositions and sets. n-truncated type theory is consistent with [n-1 level univalence](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.00260).

Comment: @ZhenLin Well I do fully admit that not every groupid is closed, but I would still help there is a common formalism that works whether or not there are types for internalized isomorphism.

Comment: @Ericson2314 The only groupoid with finite products – never mind cartesian closed – is the trivial one.